Dependency Web-Flux not Found on pom.xml (Springboot)
I'm trying to add the WebFlux dependency to my pom.xml, but Maven can't find it. I'm using Intellij.

I tried deleting the pom.xml file and running mvn clean install -U, but it didn't work.
When I include the dependency in pom.xml and run mvn clean install, the build fails.
I also tried the Maven > Reload Project and also didn't work. Error message:

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:3.4.0-RC1 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced


Remove the version tag. The version is managed by the Spring Boot Starter Parent (when in use) or the spring boot bom when used instead of the parent. Don't specify versions for starters as that will lead to version conflicts and harder upgrades.

This dependency doesn't exist yet (as of Nov 13, 2024). At least not in Maven Central.
See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-webflux.
Latest version is 3.3.5, published in October 24, 2024.

It exists if you use the Spring Milestones repository though if you really need this version.
See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-webflux?repo=springio-milestone
You'd need to configure this additional repository in your Maven settings or Maven project. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Thanks for the answer. I fixed the issue, I got an older version of the web flux dependency and deleted the test class that Spring creates, after doing this I was able to use the  `mvn clean install -U´ and this time the build not failed and Maven was able to download the dependency.
